# Convert String to dictionary using NSJSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to convert string to dictionary.We are using `NSJSON` but getting `nil` value

```
 NSString *decryptstr = [CTAES decrypt:text];
```

decryptstr contains below data

```
    {
    "status":"200","description":"OK","count":"4","reg_flag":1,"cars":

[],"appointments_count":"0","addbymecars":[{"gallery":

[],"imagescount":0,"id":"1924453","mypage_list_flag":0,"appointment_date":"",
"listing_status":"Active","sellername":"test ","sellernumber":"+918888888888","email":"ufhwifuw@gmail.com","make":"Hyundai","model":"i20","model_type":"Asta 1.4 CRDI","listing_type":"","listing_sorting_order":"","band_color":"","price":"65,59,595\/-","state":"Telangana","city":"Hyderabad","area":"","mfgyear":"2013","color":"Green","owner":"2","user_type":"person","dealer_id":"1503181","isfeatured":"0","fueltype":"Diesel","pincode":"0","mileage":"89,89,898","app_latitude":"","app_longitude":"","certification":"n","certification_text":"","images":{"ldpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable80x60.jpg","mdpi":
"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable100x75.jpg","hdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable150x113.jpg","xhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable200x150.jpg","xxhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable300x225.jpg"},"usedcarshortlist":"0","postingdate":"04-Jan-2016","mobile_link":"http:\/\/testm.cartrade.com\/L1924453","transmission":
"Manual"},{"gallery":[],"imagescount":0,"id":"1924742","mypage_list_flag":0,"appointment_date":"","listing_status":"Active","sellername":"yuyu ","sellernumber":"+919898889989","email":"jhhgj@gmail.com","make":"Maruti Suzuki","model":"800","model_type":"AC","listing_type":"","listing_sorting_order":"","band_color":"","price":"15,64,654\/-","state":"Delhi","city":"New Delhi","area":"","mfgyear":"2014","color":"","owner":"1","user_type":"person","dealer_id":"1484907","isfeatured":"0","fueltype":"Petrol","pincode":"110001","mileage":"1,233","app_latitude":"28.6182","app_longitude":"77.2233",
"certification":"n","certification_text":"","images":{"ldpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable80x60.jpg","mdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable100x75.jpg","hdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable150x113.jpg","xhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable200x150.jpg","xxhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable300x225.jpg"},"usedcarshortlist":"0","postingdate":"05-Feb-2016","mobile_link":"http:\/\/testm.cartrade.com\/L1924742","transmission":"Manual"},{"gallery":[],"imagescount":0,"id":"1924641","mypage_list_flag":0,"appointment_date":"","listing_status":"Active","sellername":"vcnvmcx ","sellernumber":"+919812345687","email":"chk@gmail.com","make":"Maruti Suzuki","model":"Alto 800","model_type":"LX","listing_type":"","listing_sorting_order":"",
"band_color":"","price":"2,50,000\/-","state":"Maharashtra","city":"Mumbai","area":"New Hyderabad","mfgyear":"2015","color":"","owner":"1","user_type":"person","dealer_id":"1503221","isfeatured":"0","fueltype":"Petrol","pincode":"500001","mileage":"50,000","app_latitude":"17.3897","app_longitude":"78.478","certification":"n","certification_text":"","images":{"ldpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable80x60.jpg","mdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable100x75.jpg","hdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable150x113.jpg","xhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable200x150.jpg","xxhdpi":"http:\/\/imagecdn.cartrade.com\/notavailable300x225.jpg"},
"usedcarshortlist":"1","postingdate":"03-Feb-2016","mobile_link":"http:\/\/testm.cartrade.com\/L1924641","transmission":"Manual"
    }
    ]}
```

using `NSJSON`

```
 NSError *error;

NSData *jsonData = [decryptstr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *returndict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                           options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                             error:&error];
```

returndict getting nil value.

Comment: What are you storing in `finalstr ` ?

Comment: What error do you get in the `NSError` instance?

Comment: oh sorry that is decryptstr

Comment: i am not getting any error.... dictionary contains nil

Comment: is `jsonData` nil, too?

Comment: in jsonData getting bytes

Comment: @ vadian     in NSError  getting error like      "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Garbage at end." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}"

Comment: It would be very helpful to include those error messages in the question! The error says that there is text at the end of the JSON which is not valid. Maybe an HTML snippet.

Comment: I have added answer to add escape character to your string. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line before convert ur string

```
NSString *decryptstr = [CTAES decrypt:text];
decryptstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",[decryptstr UTF8String]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created one JSON file and copied your JSON data.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&err];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string doesn't contain any escape characters, which Objective-C cann't read directly. So add escape characters to your string using following snippet.

```
// *** Get your string data ***
NSString *decryptstr = [CTAES decrypt:text];

// *** Add Escape characters to your string ***
NSString *escaped = [decryptstr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];

NSError *error;
// *** Convert escaped string to Data ***
NSData *jsonData = [escaped dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *returndict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                           options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                             error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",returndict);
```